# Git: Throw away local changes for one directory?

Tags: git

Can I throw away local changes for one directory?

I changed a group of files, most I want to commit but there is a directory for which I don't want to commit any of the changes I made. How do i throw just those changes away while still keeping the others intact?

Thanks!

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: What's the problem? Just don't stage the files from the directory. Stage the rest and commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a commit you first have to choose which files to add to a commit. By doing a

```
git commit -a
```

you add all the files to the commit. Instead of that, you can first choose which files to add to the commit using

```
git add [file/directory]
```

You can, in this way, specify what files to add to the commit, either one by one, or adding directories all together. You can `git add` all directories that you want. You can always check using

```
git status
```

which files are included in the commit and which are not. When you add the files that you desire and leave the rest, you do a `git commit` and then you can do a `git checkout` on the files that you want to revert, all you can store all of them in the stash using `git stash`.

**Edit**: On the other hand, there are multiple IDEs that have incorporated visual git tools, which you can easily use to select files to be commited.

Answer (score 0):

You could first add all changes, and then do a `git reset directory/`, then `git commit`. This will commit stage everything else, but does not include the directory in the commit.

If you need to get rid of the local modifications in that directory, you can run `git reset --hard` after committing.

Answer (score 0):

You can selectively choose things you want to commit with:

```
git add -p #(or git add --patch)
```

Explanation from git man page

```
   -p, --patch
       Interactively choose hunks of patch between the index and the work tree and add them to the
       index. This gives the user a chance to review the difference before adding modified contents
       to the index.

       This effectively runs add --interactive, but bypasses the initial command menu and directly
       jumps to the patch subcommand. See "Interactive mode" for details.
```

If you do not want to commit anything from that folder forever, you can add it to `.gitignore` file and git would permanently ignore any change to that folder, view sample gitignore files [here](http://www.sujee.net/tech/articles/gitignore/)